# High load on server because of one query

Tags: mysql, performance, centos, wordpress, query-performance

I have one query running from last stable version of wordpress on causing high load on my centos 6.7 server

I enabled slow query log thought /etc/my.cnf file to record which sql cause this problem and i found this one

```
# User@Host: database_Swhf[database_Swhf] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 5.129712  Lock_time: 0.000107 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 331084
use database_Swhf;
SET timestamp=1450396105;
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_frposts.ID 
FROM wp_frposts  
  INNER JOIN wp_frterm_relationships 
    ON (wp_frposts.ID = wp_frterm_relationships.object_id) 
WHERE 1=1  
  AND wp_frposts.ID NOT IN (37615) 
  AND ( 
          (
            SELECT COUNT(1)
            FROM wp_frterm_relationships
            WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN
                (192471,192472,192473,192474,192475,
                 192476,192477,192478,192479,192480,
                 192481,192482,192483,192484,192485,
                 192486,192487,192488,192489,192490,192491)
            AND object_id = wp_frposts.ID
          ) = 21 
      AND 
          (
            SELECT COUNT(1)
            FROM wp_frterm_relationships
            WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (34)
            AND object_id = wp_frposts.ID
          ) = 1 
      AND 
          wp_frterm_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (13)
      ) 
  AND wp_frposts.post_type = 'post' 
  AND (wp_frposts.post_status = 'publish') 
GROUP BY wp_frposts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_frposts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 4;
```

I don't know how to fix this query and make it stop causing these problems to my server.

Comment: What is the query supposed to do and who wrote it?

Comment: Show the table definitions.

Comment: Provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`